# Finding the attr values of input or span after they are loaded via .load()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, live

I have a form that does a lookup on a database the lookup is done using `load()`. This is fine.

What I've like to do is to read the value of an input which is returned via the php.
I was thinking that I needed to use the `.live()` method but I'm not certain how.

My current code is:

```
var recordCount = $("input[name=noOfCusts]").val();
console.log("Number is " + recordCount)
```

So `input[name=noOfCusts]` is loaded from PHP so I can't get at it. I just get a value of undefined.

How do I roll live() into `var recordCount = $("input[name=noOfCusts]").val();`

Thanks

My load code is

```
$("input[name=findCust]").keyup(function(){
    var key = $(this).val();
    var type = 1;
    $("div#CustomerResults").html("<img src='../images/loading.gif' alt='loading'/>").delay('500').load("../../ajax/customerFinder.php",{"key":key,"type":type}).fadeIn(300);



    //#############################################
    // Extra bit to make the search form work with a return
    $("input[name=findCust]").live('keyup',function(){
        var recordCount = $("input[name=noOfCusts]").val();
        console.log("Number is " + recordCount)
    });

    //var recordCount = $("input[name=noOfCusts]").find("input[name=noOfCusts]").val();
    //
    //$('input[name="noOfCusts"]').val(data);
    //console.log("Number is " + data)
    //#############################################
});
```

Comment: is `input[name=noOfCusts]` in the DOM when you perform that code?

Comment: can you show us your `load()` script

Comment: Please note that quotes are mandatory: `$("input[name='noOfCusts;]").val();`

Comment: @PeeHaa: they are not mandatory, they are only recommended

Comment: The load script just returns

echo '<input type="hidden" name="noOfCusts" value="'.$count.'"/>';

Comment: @user1463462: so it returns just a html with one tag?

Comment: @zerkms Hmmm. You seem to be right. However they did state so in [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), but they have [changed it](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11300). Now they have stated something about it on [the selectors main page](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/). But when I try to find this in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS3/Selectors#Attribute_Selector) I cannot find anything about when to use quotes. Do you have a link to the spec about the use of quotes by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning an HTML `input` tag, return just the value for that input that is already present within HTML DOM.

Then in load call on success set the obtained value to that input:

```js
// success
$('input[name="noOfCusts"]').val(data);
alert(data);
```

Comment: Thought of that to be honest but it's a lot of work to change the existing .load() to a proper ajax call.

Comment: @user1463462 Please, edit Your question and add whole `load()` call code... This way we have nothing to work with...